# Custom live tile for windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, live-tile

I created an app that has my own custom live tile in it.
There are three size of live tile user controls created but added here is only one size(see codes) and I need to add the same for other two sizes(Medium and Small tile).

Here's the source - [Custom Live Tile](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andy_wigley/archive/2013/04/10/live-apps-creating-custom-tile-and-lock-screen-images.aspx)

Below is the code for the Wide Tile...

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
   {
       // Render the new tile image
       RenderImageLibrary.WideTileControl wtc = 
            new RenderImageLibrary.WideTileControl(tempMain, descr, loc);
       wtc.SaveJpegComplete += async (s, args) =>
       {
           try
           {
              if (args.Success)
              {
                 // Set the tile image URI - "isostore:/" is important! Note that the control already
                 // puts the image into /Shared/ShellContent which is where tile images in the local folder must be
                 Uri tileImageUri = new Uri("isostore:/" + args.ImageFileName, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
                 Debug.WriteLine(tileImageUri.ToString());

                 // Set the tile image
                 FlipTileData ftd = new FlipTileData();
                 ftd.WideBackgroundImage = tileImageUri;

                 ShellTile.ActiveTiles.First().Update(ftd);
              }
              else
              {
                 Debug.WriteLine(args.Exception.ToString());
              }
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
              Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
           }
       };
       wtc.BeginSaveJpeg();
   });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

`ftd.BackgroundImage = tileImageUri;
ftd.SmallBackgroundImage = tileImageUri;`

For more information on FlipTileData you can refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.shell.fliptiledata

Comment: I know about this, but i also want to add custom small tile.

Comment: @RaghavMac What do you want to do with your small tile that is different from the large one? I didn't get it...

Comment: I have a text on the medium tile and when i used the `tileImageUri` for small tile as well, that text is even small and not almost visible.

Comment: Is the text on the image itself?
You can chose different images for `ftd.BackgroundImage` and for `ftd.SmallBackgroundImage`. It doesn't need to be the `tileImageUri`. You can declare other images.

Comment: I did that, i created another UserControl for small tile but dont know how to implement here. Thats what my post describes.

Comment: I guess that now I understood what you want to do here.

You have to create the new UserControl and then:

`RenderImageLibrary.WideTileControl newSmallWtc = new RenderImageLibrary.WideTileControl("Whatever Text");

newSmallWtc.SaveJpegComplete += async (s, args) => {`


(...)and then

`FlipTileData ftd = new FlipTileData();
ftd.BackgroundImage = tileImageUri;
ftd.Title = "Set by BG agent";

ShellTile.ActiveTiles.First().Update(ftd);`

It should do it.